# installing URW Classico on Mac OS texlive 2010

Tags: fonts, installing

I have downloaded the zip file from `http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/urw/classico/uop.zip` and unzipped the content into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/` and then run:

```
$ sudo texhash
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-var/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

Followed by:

```
$ sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=uop.map
updmap: This is updmap, version $Id: updmap 17423 2010-03-11 17:53:34Z karl $
updmap: using transcript file `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log'
updmap: initial config file is `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg'
updmap: configuration (updmap.cfg) unchanged. Map files will not be recreated.
```

However when I try using `\renewcommand*\sfdefault{uop}` I get:

```
[...]
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+432/600 --dpi 432 uopr8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for uopr8r.
mktexpk: perhaps uopr8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file uopr8r): Font uopr8r at 432 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
[...]
```

It feels wrong that updmap-sys said: `configuration (updmap.cfg) unchanged. Map files will not be recreated.` But I feel that I have followed the instructions and don't know what I can do differently. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Oh, btw I might have run the updmap-sys command once before with stuff placed in the wrong location but I would imagine it possible to re-run it.

Comment: Does the file  `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` contain the line `Map uop.map`?

Comment: Also, is there a file called `updmap.cfg` in `~/Library/texlive/2010/texmf-config/web2c/`?

Comment: No the file `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` does not contain `Map uop.map`. 

As for the other thing I don't even have a `Library/texlive` folder, and according to the output of `updmap-sys` in my question it looked for and found such a file at `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` isn't that enough?

Comment: Can you manually add the line `Map uop.map` to `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` and then run `sudo updmap-sys`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg`, not `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`. Is `Map uop.map` present in the former file?

Comment: Okey after adding uop.map to `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` the updmap-sys ran. I still get `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file uopr8r): Font uopr8r at 432 not found` though.

Comment: To which `updmap.cfg` did you add the line? The one in `texmf-config` or the one in `texmf`?

Comment: Yea `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` contains the row: `Map uop.map`. Both files contain that row now. :)

Comment: @Michael Ummels: Okey I am confused now, I seem to have edited the `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` one but both files contain that row now.

Comment: Okay, can you check whether `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` contains a reference to uopr8r? :-)

Comment: @jonalv: Then, I guess the one in `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` was correctly generated by `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=uop.map`...

Comment: @Michael Ummels: yea, `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` contains the row: `uopr8r URWClassico-Reg <8r.enc <uopr8a.pfb "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the source of this problems is a mix of updmap-sys and updmap commands. updmap creates local map-files (and I think also cfg-files) which hides the system wide map-files created by updmap-sys.

You could at first try to disable and then to reenable the map-file to force updmap-sys to generate map-files. Then check if you document actually use this new map-file.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea but how do I do that? `sudo updmap-sys --disable Map=uop.map` gives me the same message...

Why wouldn't the document use the map-file? And how to check that? This answer generates more questions than it answers... :/

Comment: Looking at your pathes above it looks as if the installation folder `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/` is not in the texhash list. Are you sure you did put the files in the correct tree?

Comment: I think it is in the list: it is the first entry.

Comment: Actually, no I am not sure... However I know I am supposed to place them in a tree with the root in a folder named `texmf-local` and the folder `/usr/local/texlive/2010/` does not contain such a folder. Which makes sense since as I understand things the point of the `texmf-local` is that it should be used for files that should be migrated the day I switch to version 2011. So if it is not the `texmf-local` folder in the root that contains the 2009 and 2010 versions then where else could the correct tree be?

Comment: Sorry I wrote nonsense. `/usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local/` is `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`. Run a small document with pdftex and check at the end of the log-file the path of the pdftex.map.

Comment: Hm seems like my `pdflatex` uses the file: `~/Library/texlive/2010/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` but I am not sure whether that is the one updmap-sys was changing. How can you tell? It claims to have been generated by `updmap` and not `updmap-sys`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: So if there are files generated by updmap should I try to run that instead of updmap-sys in order to get this messy situation to untangle?

Comment: I have miktex not texlive. And I have windows not macOX. So identifying pathes is difficult for me.  In miktex I would run (the equivalent) of `updmap-sys --verbose ...` to find out which cfg it uses and which map-file it creates. You can naturally try to run `updmap` but do it with `--verbose` (I hope it knows `--verbose`) and note the maps it creates so that you can remove them if it doesn't work or if you want to use updmap-sys again.

Comment: There is no verbose :(

Comment: Ah, this explains everything. :-) But before, you claimed that you don't have a folder in ~/Library/texlive? Are you sure you have never run `updmap` (as opposed to `updmap-sys`).?

Comment: So, to get URW Classico working, it should suffice to run `updmap --enable Map=uop.map` (as a normal user, not with sudo).

Comment: I am beginning to think I have run `updmap` yea. I was trying to install some other font and I was following some other instruction. (I am not sure whether it was on this machine or on my Ubuntu setup) but since I just collected all my courage and ran `updmap` a few moments ago and since after I did that everything suddenly worked I am beginning to think I must have indeed run `updmap` before. Now all that remains is to do this thing on my Ubuntu machine as well. I wonder if that is going to be any easier... :)

Comment: On the other hand, if you don't have any fonts installed in `~/Library/texmf`, it might be the best thing to switch to updmap-sys. I guess, it suffices to remove the map files in `~/Library/texlive/2010/texmf-var/fonts/map`.